# How to get api key from google for push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, api-key

I have followed [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)
tutorial for android push notification. I am not getting services-> api access menu and api key. How to get API key? The UI is not showing API key, I have created the project too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used an old tutorial that describes the old UI of Google APIs.
In the new UI you need to do the following ([source](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#access-key)):

> To obtain an API key:
>
> ```
> 1. In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth > Registered apps.
> 2. Click Register app.
> 3. In the Name field, type your app's name.
> 4. Click Android > Accessing APIs directly from Android.
> 5. Under Android identification, type the package name for your app.
> 6. Enter an SHA1 fingerprint. To get this value, follow the instructions in the 
>    console help.
> 7. Click Register.
> 8. In the new page, open the Android Key section and copy the API key. You will
>    need the API key later on to perform authentication in your application server.
> ```
>
> Note: If you need to rotate the key, click the "recycle key" icon. A new key will
>   be created. If you think the key has been compromised
>   and you want to delete it immediately, you can accomplish this by
>   deleting the app from the console. Then create a new entry for the app
>   with the same SHA1 and package name.

To get the SHA1 fingerprint in step 6 you can use the command:

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\myusername\.android\debug.keystore -list -v`

(and enter the default password `android` at the prompt)

Comment: I have followed these steps too, but I didnt see Registered apps under APIs and auth section. Where is that actually??

Comment: @BarcelonaTsandesh see the screenshot [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677709/issue-with-registration-app-in-gcm/20683976#20683976)

Comment: @BarcelonaTsandesh They changed the API again. Now you have to click `APIs & auth` > `Credentials` to create API key.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate api key by visiting https://cloud.google.com/console. 
You need to activate api for Google Cloud Messaging Service.

Also there is provision for limiting ip addresses to connect to your api. Your ip address is provided by default. You may need to remove that to use GCM using above tutorial.

For more help: check [this](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try to visit this link without redirecting to **new cloud** [GCM](https://code.google.com/apis/console). This link will redirect to new google could but you need to click **go back** option to see API access menu. You will see the Message like **Welcome to the new Google Developers Console! Prefer the old console? Go back | Dismiss**.

Comment: +1, Google keeps on redirecting me to the new cloud GCM. I bookmark this link, https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect and it stops redirecting