# issue with registration app in GCM

Tags: android, google-api, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I following this tutorial [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) to enable push notification in my android app. I've already created an user account in GCM then created a new project, enabled GCM service by toggling ON the button. Now I have to obtain my API key. Following the instructions of tutorial I should have to go:

In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth > Registered apps.
Click Register app.

But there is no Registered apps there. Could you explain me how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is a `Registered apps` link.

Here it is:

[image]

EDIT :

Tried to access the cloud console again, this time the UI was different :

[image]

You have to click on CREATE NEW KEY.

Comment: I don't see it: ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://postimg.org/image/8q6lpcffd/

Comment: @user3107388 It looks like they changed the UI once more and now you have to select Credentials and then Create New Key for public API Access. Then you select Server Key to create the API Key.

Answer (score 1):

I've been attempting to create an instance of the php server based service.
I needed a client ID and a private key file. I haven't needed api key yet, but I'll explain how I got that too.

To obtain these from where you are now it appears you need to do this:

1. Go into APIs and Auth > Credentials
2. Under OAuth click CREATE NEW CLIENT ID and use the service account option. This will provide access to a JSON file and private key file. Download them both to somewhere in your local project. The JSON file contains a client key among other things. The private key is what it says on the tin.

Furthermore, you can obtain an API key in this way:

1. Under Public API Access click CREATE NEW KEY and select your option. (In my case I'm trying to connect via PHP so I chose Server Key). I'm using 0.0.0.0/32 to enable any IP - not very secure, but I'm only prototyping at this point.

Hope this helps...

Comment: At the time I wrote this, I have what appears to be a valid php service object.