# How to obtain GCM API Key, No Registered Apps in the menu

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-console

I am kinda stuck trying to obtain GCM API Key. I am developing an Android App with push notifications feature enabled. I am following http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html to obtain API key. But it seems that `Registered App` is not there - see screenshot below. 
[image: Google Cloud Console missing Registered App link]
How can I get the `Registered App` link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like they changed the UI once more and now you have to select `Credentials` and then `Create New Key` for public API Access. Then you select `Server Key` to create the API Key.

Please see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677709/issue-with-registration-app-in-gcm/).